# I'm trying to use python3 and beautifulsoup4 to pull data for my school project

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have many classes which having name `marginBegin`. I want to find Date in this whole code.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="marginBegin">
  <dl>
    <dt><label>Delivered On:</label></dt>
    <!--fsrHiddenBlockStart--><dd><!--fsrHiddenBlockStart-->
    Friday, &nbsp;06/17/2016
    at&nbsp;3:02 P.M.
      <!--fsrHiddenBlockEnd--></dd><!--fsrHiddenBlockEnd-->
  </dl>
```

My Result:

> 06/17/2016

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
soup = BeautifulSoup(open("file.html"))
for link in soup.findAll("div", { "class" : "marginBegin" }):
    string= link.contents[1].findAll("dd")
    date=re.search(r'(\d+/\d+/\d+)',(str(string[0])))
    print(date.group(1))
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much dear